# Limit of an iterated function system

Tags: dynamical-systems, iterated-function-system

Consider the function $h(x) = 2x(1-x).$ My goal is to find
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} h^n \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ),$$
where $h^n (x_0)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ iterate of the function $h(x)$ at the point $x_0.$ I have that
$$h^0 \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \frac{3}{8} = .375.$$
$$h^1 \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \frac{3}{8} \left ( \frac{5}{4} \right ) = .46875.$$
$$h^2 \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \frac{3}{8} \left ( \frac{85}{64} \right ) = .4980.$$
It appears that we are approaching $\frac{1}{2}$. But, how do I prove this? I do not see an obvious closed form solution for the limit.

Comment: Let $x_n=h^n(1/4)$. Assume that $1/2>x_{n}\geq x_{n-1}>0$. Then $x_{n+1}=h(x_n)=2x_n(1-x_n)\geq x_n$, since this is equivalent to $x_n<1/2$. Also $x_{n+1}=2x_n(1-x_n)<1/2$, since this is implied by $x_n\neq 1/2$. Therefore, the sequence is monotone and bounded. So, it has a limit $L$. Applying limit to both sides of $x_{n+1}=h(x_n)$ you get that $L=2L(1-L)$. This has solutions $L=1/2$ and $L=0$. But the limit can't be $0$ because the sequence is positive and increasing.

Comment: This is the logistic map with $r=2$. Just make a [cobweb plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) and it should be obvious.

Comment: Or more directly, consider $y_n=1-2x_n$, then $y_{n+1}=y_n^2$.